# Quicksilver in OS X does not show up in menubar or tab items

Tags: macos, quicksilver

I can't get Quicksilver to show up in the menubar or the tab items. Which also means I can't get to any of the preferences.

I tried reinstalling a few times, but that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Have you tried clearing its preferences from `~/Library/Preferences/` (you can go there with ⇧⌘G from Finder)? Do you get through the setup properly? What happens when you press the default keyboard shortcut for Quicksilver? Does it appear?

Answer (score 1):

To get to the preferences: Invoke Quicksliver, then hit `⌘`+`,`

Once you're in Preferences, under Application and General you can turn off and on "Show icon in dock" and "show icon in menu bar" - see photo below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Quicksilver is already running in the backround and you open it again (for example from Finder or Spotlight), it should show the launcher window. You can then open the preferences with ⌘, or from the triangle menu.